# Extract text from String

Tags: android, string

I have one String and into this string I have a url between two characters # such as "Hello world #http://thisurl# my name is Pippo" I want to take the url (http://thisurl) between two #.

How can I do ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      String data[] = str.split("#"); //spilliting string and taking into array
     ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if(data[i].contains("http://"))
            urlList.add(data[i]); //if string contains "http://" it means it is url save int list.

    }
```

now you can get all uls from `urlList.get(i)` method.

this urlList will give you all the urls available in the string. I dint applied any null or other check. Apply it and try. If want something else try modifying content and checks.

Comment: I can have multiple url in the text exemple : Hello world #http://url1# how are #http://url2# you ?

Comment: i have edited my answer it is now general and will find all urls in the string , and return u a list of Url's.
View my answer again

Comment: Ok it's good but I can do a String such as : "Hello world http://www.url_no_take how are #http://www.url_take# you ? Ok thanks ! visit my site http://url_no_take" In this case I must take only #http://www.url_take#

Answer (score 1):

Try String.split(). You really should be trying to google these things first.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example - http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

The split method divides a string into several strings and store them into an array using a delimiter which can be defined by you. 
the second element in the resulting array will be your URL